# What does ES1 refer to in this picture?

Tags: stocks

Is it some stock?

[image]

Comment: Very mysterious indeed.

Comment: Did you ask them?

Answer (score 6):

ES1 is the Bloomberg symbol for the CME E-mini S&P 500 front-month [continuous contract](http://www.premiumdata.net/support/futurescontinuous.php).  ES2, ES3, etc. will likewise yield the 2nd and 3rd months.  Which exact futures contract this symbol refers to will change about once a month.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a Bloomberg terminal. And like @Jer said, it would appear to be the symbol for the S&P 500 E-mini index future. Although it doesn't look right all on its own, as it should have a modifier indicating the month (or quarter) of expiry.

However, since it appears on a Bloomberg terminal in the image, I checked a [**source for Bloomberg Symbol Lists**](http://terminal.tradesignalonline.com/wiki/3/Bloomberg+Symbollists) and found one of two possibilities for ES1. It is most likely the S&P 500 e-mini future:

> CME E-Mini Futures  E-Mini S&P 500    ES1 INDEX

the only alternative was

> LIFFE 3 Month Euroswiss   ES1 COMDTY

I think the former is far more likely, as the latter has the COMDTY commodity tag instead of INDEX as the tag in the image. Also, it isn't the ESI which pertains to Ethibel Sustainability Indices and something with the Eurozone (also Bloomberg Indices).

Here we go! Excerpt straight is from a presentation [**presentation on charting from a business school PDF**](http://belkcollegeofbusiness.uncc.edu/jrussell/SMIF/Charting_and_Technicals_Presentation.pdf) see pp.12-13, and appears to be a straight excerpt from September 2007 Bloomberg documentation. I didn't know any other way to imbed it besides taking a screen shot then uploading to imgur. Or of course, see pp.12-13 in the referenced PDF I've attached.
[image: Bloomberg Single Security for ES1 Index using VBAR Function]

See

> 1. Enter an underlying security. `Example: ES1 <Index> VBAR <GO>`...

Answer (score 0):

That looks very much like an S&P 500 E-Mini index future.  However, ES1 is a strange symbol.  Futures have the month of expiry encoded in their symbol as well:  http://commodities.about.com/od/understandingthebasics/ss/futurescontract_3.htm

For example, the September 2011 future in this series would be ESU1.

I'm not very familiar with Bloomberg so perhaps this is the front contract (i.e. the one that's closest to expiry (in the is case the September 2011 one)).

Only problem is that prices don't exactly match what CME has (high of 1190 and low of 1186.25, for when this page gets out of date):  http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500.html  - but they are so close I suspect it must be some sort of S&P 500 index future.